# Node.js parameters do not work properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, parameters, express-4

Here is my global array with json in my users.js:

```
global.users = [
    {
        'id':1,
        'name' : 'Dain',
        'age' : 24,
        'hobby' : 'gaming'
    }
];
```

The **router.get** function:

```
router.get('/:userid', function(req, res){

for(let i = 0 ; i < global.users.length ; i++){
    if(global.users[i].id === parseInt(req.params.userid, 10)){
        return res.json({
        user: global.users[i],
        message : 'Success',
        error: false
        });
    }
}
return res.status(404).json({
    message : 'User Not Found',
    error: true
});

});
```

However, the following function for getting two params does not work as expected:

```
router.get("'/:userid'+'+:age'", function(req, res){
for(let i = 0 ; i < global.users.length ; i++){
    if( (global.users[i].id === parseInt(req.params.userid, 10)) && (global.users[i].age === parseInt(req.params.age, 10))){
        return res.json({
        user: global.users[i],
        message : 'Success',
        error: false
        });
    }
}
return res.status(404).json({
    message : 'User Not Found',
    error: true
});

});
```

Even if I pass age as follows in the url, it still returns the user info.

```
http://localhost:8080/users/1+226
```

Since 226 is not any of the ages defined, it must return:

```
{
    message : 'User Not Found',
    error: true
}
```

Even if I put any age, it still returns the values. Please guide.

```
http://localhost:8080/users/1+24
```

Comment: router.get("'/:userid'+'+:age'" i think this should be router.get('/:userid/:age/'

Comment: you are right andreas, but I want to show
    http://localhost:8080/users/1+24
in the URL

Comment: your routes is not correct

Comment: Are you sure your loop is working fine?and you if condition always get true?

Comment: @abdulbarik,... yes sir

Comment: @Newbee Dev
Where at, sir?

Comment: Debug your both conditions and check what are the values are you getting and it'll be better if you show here

Answer (score 1):

instead of creating a loop that check if the specific fields matches. use underscoreJS it is better in finding data inside array http://underscorejs.org/#findWhere

Note: (Install module underscore first)

```
var _ = require('underscore');

var user = _.findWhere(global.users, {
    id: req.params.userid,
    age:  req.params.age
});

if (user !== null) {
    return res.json({
        user: user,
        message : 'Success',
        error: false
    });
} else {
    return res.status(404).json({
        message : 'User Not Found',
        error: true
    });
}
```